# Почему код выводит 2 раза одно и то же? Как это исправить?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import requests


def page_proc(page: Soup) -> list:
    news_headers = []
    for header in page.find_all('h4', {'class': 'media-heading'}):
        news_headers.append(header.text.strip())
    return news_headers


def sandbox(base_url: str) -> list:
    headers = []
    with requests.Session() as session:
        first_page = Soup(session.get(base_url).content, 'html.parser')
        pages_qty = int(first_page.find('li', {'class': 'pager-last'}).a['href'].rpartition('=')[-1])

        headers.extend(page_proc(first_page))

        pg = Soup(session.get(base_url).content, 'html.parser')
        headers.extend(page_proc(pg))

        return headers


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(*sandbox('http://hkotso.ru/novosti'), sep='\n')
```

Почему код выводит 2 раза одно и то же?
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты два раза делаешь одну и ту же операцию - расширяешь список headers.
Закомментируй следующие строки:

```
pg = Soup(session.get(base_url).content, 'html.parser')
headers.extend(page_proc(pg))
```